# Fill DropDownList Value from Database using Knockout

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'm using `jQuery Ajax` to load the data from the server and then bind it using `Knockout JS`, but the values do not display in `DropDownList`.

Here is the code:

**View: Edit.cshtml**

```
...
<div class="tab-content">
    ...
    <div class="tab-pane" id="pnlLiquidation">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Liquidation/_Liquidation.cshtml", Model.LiquidationVM); }
    </div>
</div>
...
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    <script>
        ...
        var companyID = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.CompanyID);
        ...
    </script>
    ...
    <script src="~/Scripts/LiquidationSystem/account-statement.js"></script>
    ...
}
```

**View: _Liquidation.cshtml**

```
...
<div class="tab-content">
    ...
    <div class="tab-pane" id="pnlStage2Steps28_29">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Liquidation/_Stage2Steps28_29.cshtml", Model); }
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**View: _Stage2Steps28_29.cshtml**

```
...
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body" id="pnlAccountStatement">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/AccountStatement/_AccountStatement.cshtml"); }
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**View: _AccountStatement.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="#" id="lnkAddAccountStatement">Add New Statement of Accounts</a>
        <div class="form-horizontal" id="pnlAddEditAccountStatement">
            <div data-bind="if: AccountStatement">
                <h4>Update Statement of Account</h4>
                ...
            </div>

            <div data-bind="ifnot: AccountStatement()">
                <h4>Add New Statement of Account</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Type:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select class="form-control"
                                data-bind="options: Types, optionsValue: 'Value', optionsText: 'Text', optionsCaption: '-- Please Select --', value: Type"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $root.CompanyID" />
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Description:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Description" class="form-control"
                               data-bind="value: $root.Description" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Amount:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount" class="form-control"
                               data-bind="value: $root.Amount" />
                    </div>

                    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Receipt Date:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Receipt Date" class="form-control fdatepicker" readonly="readonly"
                               data-bind="value: $root.ReceiptDate" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success radius" data-bind="click: $root.create">Save</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" data-bind="click: $root.reset">Reset</a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-bind="click: $root.cancel">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h4>
            <i>
                <u>List of Statement of Accounts</u>
            </i>
        </h4>

        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript: account-statement.js**

```
function AccountStatementViewModel(companyID) {
    var self = this;

    self.AccountStatementID = ko.observable();
    self.CompanyID = ko.observable(companyID);
    self.Description = ko.observable();
    self.Amount = ko.observable();
    self.ReceiptDate = ko.observable();
    self.Type = ko.observable();

    var AccountStatement = {
        AccountStatementID: self.AccountStatementID,
        CompanyID: self.CompanyID,
        Description: self.Description,
        Amount: self.Amount,
        ReceiptDate: self.ReceiptDate,
        Type: self.Type
    }

    self.AccountStatement = ko.observable();
    self.AccountStatements = ko.observableArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: webroot + 'AccountStatement/GetAccountStatements',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { id: self.CompanyID },
        cache: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        self.AccountStatements(data);
    });

    var clearInput = function () { ... }
    self.create = function () { ... }
    self.reset = function () { ... }
    self.edit = function (accountStatement) { ... }
    self.update = function () { ... }
    self.cancel = function () { ... }
    self.delete = function (accountStatement) { ... }
}

var accountStatementVM = new AccountStatementViewModel(companyID);
ko.applyBindings(accountStatementVM, document.getElementById('pnlAccountStatement'));

var Types;

$(function () {
    $('#pnlAddEditAccountStatement').hide();

    $('#lnkAddAccountStatement').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#pnlAddEditAccountStatement').show('blind', 1000);
        $(this).hide('blind', 1000);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: webroot + 'AccountStatement/GetTypes',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log('data = ' + data);
        Types = data;
        console.log('Types[0].Text = ' + Types[0].Type);
        console.log('Types[0].Value = ' + Types[0].Description);
        console.log('Types[1].Text = ' + Types[1].Type);
        console.log('Types[1].Value = ' + Types[1].Description);
    });
});
```

When I see the console:

```
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
data = [object Object],[object Object]
account-statement.js:151 Types[0].Text = Receipts
account-statement.js:152 Types[0].Value = Receipts
account-statement.js:153 Types[1].Text = Payment
account-statement.js:154 Types[1].Value = Payment
```

**Controller: AccountStatementController.cs**

```
public JsonResult GetTypes()
{
    List<SelectListItem> types = new List<SelectListItem>
    { 
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Receipts",
            Value = "Receipts"
        },
        new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = "Payment",
            Value = "Payment"
        }
    };
}
```

Can I use `SelectListItem` rather than create the View Model? I've tried to create `AccountStatementTypeViewModel.cs` and replace the `SelectListItem`.

**AccountStatementTypeViewModel.cs**

```
public class AccountStatementTypeViewModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

update the `GetTypes()` method

```
public JsonResult GetTypes()
{
    List<AccountStatementTypeViewModel> types = new List<AccountStatementTypeViewModel>
    {
        new AccountStatementTypeViewModel
        {
            Type = "Receipts",
            Description = "Receipts"
        },
        new AccountStatementTypeViewModel
        {
            Type = "Payment",
            Description = "Payment"
        }
    };
    return Json(types, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

update the select tag in **_AccountStatement.cshtml**

```
<select class="form-control"
        data-bind="options: Types, optionsValue: 'Type', optionsText: 'Description', value: Type"></select>
```

but the result is same, it cannot bind into the DropDownList value.

I've followed the code from this [site](https://ddmvc4.codeplex.com/) and download the source code and see the code how do they fill the Phone Type dropdownlist. The tutorial use ASP.NET MVC 4, jQuery 1.8.3, and Knockout 2.2.0, but mine using ASP.NET MVC 5, jQuery 2.1.4, and Knockout 3.3.0. Is there any problem with the version differences?

Comment: As `types` is not a ko function (observableArray) as you are doing a ajax to fill variable `types`  . As types is a plain js variable it wont update the view once your view is rendered & if you assign data via ajax later . Make it a observableArray which will do it for you and use `()` convention  .

Comment: @supercool ok I'll give it a try but can you explain why in the link above, if you download the source code, it can be loaded without make it as ko function (observableArray) and it is a plain js variable?

Comment: @SirwanAfifi, it doesn't work

Comment: You should show the minimum code necessary to understand the problem, not directly copy all the code that can have something to do with your problem. Most people, including me, will skip your question.

Comment: @Willy in the link `phoneTypeData` is initialized with data (array) straight away . were as , in your case ,you are assigning data you getting only after view rendering is done(you don't have ready-made data available , only it is available after a successful ajax call . by that time view part is rendered with types=null ) not before . js is asynchronous .